# In lua, if a variable contained a table element, if I then remove the table element from the actual table, does the variable get set to nil?

Tags: arrays, lua

new to programming in Lua. Suppose I have a variable that contains a table element. For instance, Let objects be an array of something and I also have a variable 'a'.

a = objects[2] is what I do for some functionality in my program. If I then table.remove the 2nd element in the objects table, does 'a' get set to nil automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it out?

```
local objects = {{}, {}}
local a = objects[2]
table.remove(objects, 2)

print("objects[2]", objects[2])
print("a", a)
```

Prints:

```
objects[2]  nil
a   table: 0x11196d0 (this value will be different for you)
```

You see `a` is not `nil`!

`local objects = {{}, {}}` is equivalent to

```
do
   -- this line creates a table and a local reference to that table named objects
  local objects = {}
  -- this line creates a table and stores a reference to it as objects[1]
  objects[1] = {}
  -- this line creates a table and stores a reference to it as objects[2]
  objects[2] = {}
end
```

Now we create `a`, a second reference to the table, `objects[2]` refers to.

```
-- this creates a local reference to the table that objects[2] refers to as a
local a = objects[2]
```

And now we remove `objects[2]`.

```
-- this line removes field 2 from the table, hence one of the referenes
table.remove(objects, 2)
```

Which in this case is equivalent to `objects[2] = nil`

That just removed one of the two existing references to that table. You assigned `nil` to `objects[2]`. So `objects[2]` no longer refers to that table.

`a` is still a reference to that table. Only if you set `a` nil there will be no more references to that table and the table may be garbage collected as it is no longer accessible. **You cannot delete tables in Lua.** You can only assign nil to all its references and let the garbage collector do its thing.